# Difference between npm install and expo install

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

I do find some blog using both npm install and expo install.
Idk what differ, they do same job

(edit) I find out that expo install are deprecated and replaced with npx expo install. But still I dont understand the main reason to use that over normal npm.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the web, React Native is not backwards compatible. This means that npm packages often need to be the exact right version for the currently installed copy of react-native in your project. Expo CLI provides a best-effort tool for doing this using a list of popular packages and the known working version combinations. Simply use the install command as a drop-in replacement for npm install:

npx expo install expo-camera Visit here to see more: https://docs.expo.dev/more/expo-cli/

Comment: oh right thank man